# Simple Node.js user management system

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a application that is made completely in JavaScript (other than the database) and I've created a simple user management system for the application.

This user management system creates a query to the database containing the user info (the database contains the user info not the query) based on a few command line arguments, decrypts the data in the database, and then prints the result to the console.

I have been programming for 2 years but am self-taught and was looking for some feedback/criticism on my code.

**Note:** Some of the modules in the Main script are not included but, for the most part, their functions should be intuitive.

**Edit:** for more information about the `DataBase` class see [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/220515/node-js-database-class-for-adodb-databases) question.

Here is my code:

#### Main script:

```
// this is a instance of a `DataBase` class:
const users = require('../../Code/MiddleWare/Database-comms/createUser').users
const lookup = require('./lookup')
const decryptAll = require('./decrypt')

void async function() {
  if(process.argv[2] === '-e') {
    console.dir(decryptAll(await lookup('Email', process.argv[3], users, process.argv[4] === '-ex')), {colors: true, depth: Infinity})
  } else if(process.argv[2] ? process.argv[2].match(/^\d+$/) : false) {
    console.dir(decryptAll(await lookup('ID', parseInt(process.argv[2]), users, process.argv[3] === '-ex', false)), {colors: true, depth: Infinity})
  } else {
    console.dir(decryptAll(await lookup('Username', process.argv[2] ? process.argv[2] : '', users, process.argv[3] === '-ex')), {colors: true, depth: Infinity})
  }
}()
```

#### "lookup" module:

```
module.exports = async function(type, string, users, exact,  encrypted = true) {
  const aes = require('../../Code/MiddleWare/Security/index').encryption.AES
   const retval = []
   await users.query('Users').then((data) => {
     for(let i of data) {
        if(encrypted ? (exact? aes.decrypt(i[type]) === string : aes.decrypt(i[type]).match(string)) : i[type] === string) {
          retval.push(i)
        }
     }
   })

   return retval.length === 0 ? false : retval
}
```

#### The "decrypt" module:

```
const decrypt = require('../../Code/MiddleWare/Security/encryption').AES.decrypt

module.exports = function(array) {
  if(!array) {
    return false    
  }

  const retval = []

  function decryptAll(obj) {
    return {ID: obj.ID, Username: decrypt(obj.Username), Email: decrypt(obj.Email), Data: decrypt(obj.Data), Password: obj.Password}
  }

  for(const i of array) {
    const item = decryptAll(i)
    item.Data = JSON.parse(item.Data)
    retval.push(item)
  }

  return retval
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Main script

- Consider using the [`commander`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander) module. One benefit you get is that it parses arguments for you. Another is that the API that declares the arguments and options  autogenerates `--help` text for you. This way, you avoid having to write all the argument parsing yourself and you get a self-documenting CLI.

### Lookup module

- Move that `require` call outside the function. You only need to import `aes` once, not on every call to the lookup function.
- When inside an `async` function, you can use `await` to write async operations in a synchronous-looking fashion. When you use `await`, you can assign the resolved value of an async operation to a variable in the same way you do it with synchronous operation.
- The code inside the `for-of` is essentially a filter operation. Consider using `array.filter()` instead, assuming `data` is just an array.
- I also recommend breaking out that nested ternary into nested `if` statements for readability. You could arrange the conditions so that it's cascading rather than nested.
- I recommend returning an empty array instead of `false` when no matches are found. This way, the consuming code won't have to deal with type checking.

### Decrypt module

- The `decryptAll` function does not appear to rely on any variables in the scope of the exported function. You can move `decryptAll` out of that function.
- That `for-of` is essentially a mapping function (transforming one array's values into another array of values). Use `array.map()` instead.
- Since `decryptAll` is just mapping select properties into a new object, you can use a combination of destructuring and shorthand properties to simplify it.

---

Bottom line, your code could look like this:

### Lookup

```
const aes = require('../../Code/MiddleWare/Security/index').encryption.AES

module.exports = async function(type, string, users, exact,  encrypted = true) {
  return await users.query('Users').filter(i => {

    // Technically, the encrypted block is a nested ternary in the
    // false portion of the first ternary. But written this way, 
    // it looks like a flat list.
    return !encrypted ? i[type] === string
      : exact ? aes.decrypt(i[type]) === string
      : aes.decrypt(i[type]).match(string)
  })
}
```

### Decrypt

```
const decrypt = require('../../Code/MiddleWare/Security/encryption').AES.decrypt

// Destructure arguments, then return an object with shorthand properties.
// Eliminates obj.
const decryptAll = ({ ID, Username, Email, Data, Password }) => {
  return { ID, Username, Email, Data, Password }
}

module.exports = function(array) {
  // We're expecting an array so the check is no longer needed.

  const retval = array.map(i => {
    const item = decryptAll(i)
    const itemWithDecryptedData = { ...item, Data: JSON.parse(item.Data) }
    return itemWithDecryptedData
  })

  return retval
}
```